$\Omega(\log T)$ minimax regret lower bound for a 2-armed bandit with Uniform rewards
I'm studying multi-armed bandit problems and encountered the following scenario:
We have a 2-armed bandit where each arm $ i $ yields rewards distributed as
$$
X_i = \mu_i + \text{Unif}[-1, 1],
$$
with the means $ \mu_i \in [0, 1] $.
I have designed an algorithm that achieves $ O(\log T) $ regret over $ T $ rounds. I also understand intuitively that there should be an $\Omega(\log T)$ lower bound on the minimax regret for any policy in this setting.
My Question:
Could someone help me with a detailed proof of this minimax lower bound? Specifically, I want to show that for any policy, there exists a bandit instance within this family where the expected regret is at least proportional to $ \log T $.
What I've Tried:
I attempted to use Pinsker's inequality and KL-divergence to prove the minimax lower bound，however, I cannot compute the KL divergence between these two reward distributions. In the case of Gaussian rewards, the KL divergence is well-defined, and lower bounds on the regret often involve terms like $ \sqrt{T} $ due to the properties of the Gaussian distribution. But for the shifted uniform distributions in this problem, the supports of the distributions for the arms in the two instances only partially overlap, and the KL divergence becomes infinite or undefined.
I suspect that alternative measures, such as the total variation distance and Hellinger distance might be more appropriate for formalizing this argument in our setting.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
